# Finding Inverse of linear transformation (basic linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inverse

Let $T$ be a linear transformation which is defined on $\mathbb{R}^3 $ by
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(3x_1,x_1-x_2,2x_1+x_2+x_3).$$
How can I find the inverse of $T$? How can i check that it even have an inverse? (Perhaps referring to some theorems that I'm not aware of)
I'm confused.

Comment: Find a representing matrix for $T$, this is, an $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ such that $T(x) = Ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Then investigate the invertibility of $A$.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for your comment. Would you mind expand your answer?

Comment: I expanded my comment to an answer, please tell me if there are still things unclear.

Comment: One way to calculate inverses is to set up the matrix $A$ that represents the transformation then create the augmented matrix $[A \vert I]$ with $I$ the identity matrix. Then use gaussian elimination until it's in the form $[I \vert B]$. Once this is done $B$ will be the inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using the definition of $T$ directly: You have the system of equations \begin{align}y_1 &= 3x_1 \\ y_2 &= x_1-x_2 \\ y_3 &= 2x_1+x_2+x_3.\end{align} To invert $T$, solve this system. If it doesn’t have a unique solution, then $T$ is not invertible.

If you prefer to work with matrices, then this is a matter of inverting the coefficient matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\1&-1&0\\2&1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Observe that this is also the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis: if you expand $A(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ you will get exactly the three expressions that define $T$. Note also that you can tell immediately that $A$ is invertible: it is a triangular matrix, so its determinant is equal to the product of its main-diagonal entries. None of them are zero, so the product is nonzero.